# Play 2.6 indicates to use a deprecated Slick class

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-2.6, play-slick

According to [Play 2.6 documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlaySlick#usage), Play-Slick should be used as follows:

```
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

class Application @Inject() (
  protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider,
  cc: ControllerComponents
)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
    extends AbstractController(cc) with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
```

Problem is that `JdbcProfile` is deprecated in Slick 3.2.x, any ideas how to deal with this? Note that I'm migrating from Play 2.5 to 2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a non-deprecated `JdbcProfile` in the `slick.jdbc` package:

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/api/index.html#slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile